# Ler array JSON no Android

Tags: java, android, json

Estou tendo dificuldades em ler um JSON no formato:

```
[{"RESULTADO":"SUCESSO"}]
```

WebClient.java:

```
//PARA LER UM JSON, USAMOS A Scanner
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (connection.getInputStream());
        String resposta = scanner.next();

        return resposta;
```

LoginTask.java:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<Login>... params) {

    ArrayList<Login> result = params[0];

    String email = result.get(0).getEmail().toString();
    String senha = result.get(0).getSenha().toString();


    LoginConverter conversor = new LoginConverter();
    String json = conversor.converteParaJSON(email, senha);

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    String resposta = client.post(json);



    return resposta;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String resposta) {

    //Toast.makeText(context, resposta, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       


    Log.i("LOG", "Teste: " + resposta);
    //AQUI ESTÁ RETORNANDO DA SEGUINTE FORMA
    //[{"RESULTADO":"SUCESSO"}]


}
```

Preciso pegar o valor de "SUCESSO" para fazer um:

```
if (resposta.equals("SUCESSO")) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "LOGADO COM SUCESSO!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {


        Toast.makeText(context, "ERRO AO LOGAR!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Tens de "parsar" esse texto para objectos. Uma boa biblioteca para isso é o gson da google.
Vê o seguinte tutorial: https://medium.com/@ssaurel/parse-and-write-json-data-in-java-with-gson-a61f8772e786

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sua variável `resposta` contém todo o conteúdo do JSON em uma `String`:

```
[{"RESULTADO":"SUCESSO"}]
```

Para transformar esta `String` em objetos JSON, basta usar as classes do pacote [`org.json`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary).

Se você olhar a [sintaxe do JSON](https://www.json.org/), verá que os colchetes (`[ ]`) delimitam um array. No caso, o array contém apenas um elemento, que por sua vez é um *object*, pois está delimitado por chaves (`{  }`).

Então primeiro criamos o array, usando a classe [`JSONArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray). Em seguida, pegamos o primeiro elemento do array, que será um [`JSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject):

```
String resposta = "[{\"RESULTADO\":\"SUCESSO\"}]";
// criar o JSONArray
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(resposta);
// pegar o primeiro elemento
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

Agora o `jsonObject` possui o conteúdo `{"RESULTADO":"SUCESSO"}`. Um *object* é simplesmente um conjunto de vários pares chave/valor. No caso, temos apenas uma chave (`"RESULTADO"`), cujo valor é a string `"SUCESSO"`. Então basta pegar o valor desta chave e comparar com a `String` que você quer:

```
if ("SUCESSO".equals(jsonObject.getString("RESULTADO"))) {
    // sucesso
}
```

Comment: Já tentei fazer isso JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray(resposta); mas ele reclama o seguinte erro "JsonArray() in JsonArray cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)"

Comment: @Barraviera Vc está usando a classe org.json.JSONArray?

Comment: Desculpa, amigo. Eu estava fazendo burrada e usado o JsonArray do (com.google.gson). Agora que corrigi, deu certo.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode construir algo mais orientado a objeto.

A ideia é ter um objeto que represente a resposta, com um campo `resultado`. O retorno da API (uma `String`) seria mapeada para essa classe, que permitiria, com um simples *getter*, acessar o resultado. Uma das principais vantagens dessa abordagem é ela ser extensível (ou seja, se surgir um novo campo no json de resposta, basta acrescentar a essa classe).

A classe chamada `Resposta`, que espelha o seu json:

```
class Resposta {
    private String resultado;

    public String getResultado() {
        return resultado;
    }

    public void setResultado(String resultado) {
        this.resultado = resultado;
    }

    public Resposta(String resultado) {
        this.resultado = resultado;
    }
}
```

No método `onPostExecute(String resposta)`, você poderia então fazer o *parsing* da `String` recebida para um objeto do tipo `Resposta` usando uma API chamada [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), cuja dependência pode ser baixada [aqui](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Resposta resp = gson.fromJson(resposta, Resposta.class);
```

Neste ponto, basta acessar `resp.getResultado()` e fazer sua lógica:

```
if ("SUCESSO".equals(resp.getResultado()) {
    // sua lógica de sucesso aqui
}
```

Comment: Boa dica! Obrigado! Mas eu estava tendo problemas usando a Gson, porém a ideia de uma classe que espelha o json é uma boa.

Answer (score 2):

Agora deu certo usando o JSONArray da classe org.json.

```
try {

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(resposta);

        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

        if ("SUCESSO".equals(jsonObject.getString("RESULTADO"))) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "LOGADO COM SUCESSO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(context, "ERRO AO LOGAR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```